# EventKit: Deleted calendar reappears

Tags: ios, iphone, eventkit

I use EventKit in iOS to interact with Calendar.app. In one case, I need to delete a calendar from my app. So I use EventStore.removeCalendar(_:Commit:) function with the commit set to true. The calendar I am trying to delete is an iCloud calendar.

However, I found that after the calendar was deleted, it reappeared back itself. I am positive that it is not my mistake to add the calendar back as I have only one function regarding to creating calendars in my app and it is not called in between the deletion and reappearing.

I suspect it is iCloud who automatically adds it back. I tried to enter fly mode before deletion and the deleted calendar never reappears itself.

Has anyone experienced similar issue? If so, how can I tell iCloud that I want to delete the calendar so don't add it back.

Thanks.

Comment: This is still an issue in iOS 11, with active iCloud sync calendars created in an app keep reappearing after deletion.
Work around i use for now: Delete events only and keep the empty calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell iCloud not to add the calendar back. My guess is that when iCloud syncs stuff from a different device (that also includes updates in the given calendar), it'll treat those as higher priority, thus adding the calendar back.

This is something that occasionally happened to me while deleting the calendar through the 'Calendar' app, so the short answer is that you can't force a calendar to stay deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If that's the case, it means that there is easy way for a 3 party app to delete an iCloud calendar? I'd think the API should be smart enough to let iCloud know that this is a user initiated deletion so it can go and delete the same calendar on all devices.

Comment: My experience is if I delete the calendar from calendar.app, iCloud doesn't bring it back. I think there should be a way to achieve the same thing by using EventKit APIs.

Comment: If a calendar is deleted through the calendar.app, it can be brought back in situations when it receives a delayed sync from a different device (e.g. internet connection was off).